# How can I write a set of number of lives and make a specific gif disappear when it happens in python turtle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I made a simple python turtle game where a player has to collect items randomly generated on a screen, but whenever it hits a restricted one I want it to lose a life. I got it set for the first live, but im not quite sure how to make it work for the other two lives. This is what I did for the first one:

```
# there's 3 lives in total

live3 = trtl.Turtle()
live3.penup()
window.addshape('live3.gif') # picture of  a heart representing one life
live3.shape('heart2.gif')
live3.goto(0, -50)

def find_collosion_with_restricted():
  global playersize
  between_distance = 5
  px, py = player.pos()
  rx, ry = restricted_point.pos() # coords of the item the player can't touch
  distance = math.sqrt((px - rx)**2 + (py - ry)**2) # finds distance between to see if they touch
  if distance < between_distance:
    live3.hideturtle()
```

How can I then make it so if it hits another restricted value the second heart respawns and then for the third live as well.

Comment: Instead of `live1`, `live2`, `live3`, use a list: `lives = [live1, live2, live3]`, then loop over it and use an index to keep track of how many lives are left, or remove them from the list or something. That said, it's hard to help with such a tiny fragment of code taken from a larger project so I suggest [edit]ing the post to include a runnable, complete [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```py
lives = (life1, life2, life3)
n_of_lives = len(lives)
```

And then:

```py
if collided_with_restricted:
    n_of_lives -= 1
    lives[n_of_lives].hideturtle()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# there are 3 lives in total
lives = []

for i in range(3):
  life = trtl.Turtle()
  life.penup()
  window.addshape('heart2.gif') # picture of a heart representing one life
  life.shape('heart2.gif')
  life.goto((-i * 30), -50)
  lives.append(life)

def find_collision_with_restricted():
  global playersize
  between_distance = 5
  px, py = player.pos()
  for point in restricted_points: # list of coordinates of the restricted points
    rx, ry = point
    distance = math.sqrt((px - rx)**2 + (py - ry)**2) # finds distance between to see if they touch
    if distance < between_distance:
      life = lives.pop()
      life.hideturtle()
      if not lives:
        print("Game over") # display game over message when all lives are lost
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).